# Java battleships program: string index out of range error when converting integer to array of digits

Tags: java, arrays, string, indexing, indexoutofboundsexception

I have to write a battleships program, where the user inputs the size of the board, which is always square, and the number of ships that there will be. They then input their board, using 0 to represent water and 1 to represent a boat, and the program has to return whether the board they have entered is correct - i.e. there are the correct number of boats, and none of the boats are touching diagonally.

I have written code which aims to let the user input each line one by one (so for example, if it is a 5x5 grid, the user will have to put in 5 different numbers of 5 digits each) and each line will be put into my bidimensional array board[][]. I will then use this to check if the board is correct.

However I keep getting a string index out of range error. I know this error occurs when the code tries to access something at an index larger than the string, but I can't work out why this is happening as I have used the 'size' variable, in which the size of the grid is stored.

Here is my code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        int ships_num;
        Scanner sc;
        int size;
        int[][] board;

        sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        do {
            System.out.println("Please enter the number of boats. The maximum number is 10:  ");
            ships_num = sc.nextInt();
        } while (ships_num > 10);
        System.out.println("Number of boats: " + ships_num);

        do {
            System.out.println("Please enter the size of the board. This value is for both the length and width: ");
            size = sc.nextInt();
        } while (size > 20);
        System.out.println("Size of board: " + size);

        board = new int[size][size];

        for (int y = 0; y < size; ) {
            for (int x = 0; x < size; x++) {
                    System.out.println("Please enter the values for the first line. Values must either be 1, to represent a boat, or 0, to represent water");
                    String temp = Integer.toString(sc.nextInt());
                    for (int i = 0; i < size;i++) {
                        board[y][x]=temp.charAt(i);
                    }
                    if (x == (size-1)) {
                        x = 0;
                        y++;
                    }
                }
            }
}
```

The specific error I keep getting is: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 4. This occurs when I enter size as 5, and then put in the number 01110 for the first line.

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: The length of "temp" is smaller than "size", hence the error.   You need to check for this case and complain to the user.

Comment: @MarkLavin Hi Mark, I am getting this error when I enter size as 5, and then enter the number 01110. In this case, unless I am mistaken, the length of temp is 5, and therefore equal to size? Thanks

Comment: the problem is that the entered number -- 01110 -- is actually a four digit integer -- 1110 -- so that's the length when you string-ify it.

Comment: @MarkLavin Ahh okay that makes sense, thanks. Is there anyway that I can get the array to store 0 at the first index?

Comment: I think the key is to read the user's entry as a string, rather than as an Integer using sc.scanInt().   I'm afraid I don't know offhand how to do that with Scanner, maybe something like sc.nextInLine(<regular expression>)?   Once you have the input string "inStr", you can convert it to an array of chars with "inStr.toCharArray()".